# Subtract Business Days from a Specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to subtract a number of business days (1-15 days) from a specific date, for example subtracting **5** business days from `2013-12-27` should return `2013-12-20`, is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: If interested, I wrote a UDF to return givens holidays.    http://www.joebooth-consulting.com/sqlServer/sqlServer.html#CalendFunc

Comment: @Sparky wow thanks for sharing this ,Does your UDF only takes into account the american National holidays ??

Comment: Yep, although you can modify it to add any holiday you'd like as long as you know the rules...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This post explains how to do it using a recursive CTE:

[Business Days Calc Using Recursive CTE](http://waheedrous.wordpress.com/2013/12/24/transact-sql-user-function-to-subtract-business-days/)

Answer (score 6):

One way to do that is to pre-create a table with all the dates for couple of years in advance and select from that table. This way you can mark saturdays, sundays, holidays, etc.

Comment: In my experience, this really is the best way; it seems that no matter how hard you try to come up with a set of rules to define a "business day", the business always manages to come up with something to totally screw that up. You can try to automatically generate the table, or have a scheduled process that does it at the beginning of the year, but at least having all the data "hard-coded" gives you the opportunity to fix problems or make adjustments. And the queries are very easy to optimize to O(1). Don't be clever; be practical.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '2013/10/01'
SET @EndDate = '2013/10/31'


SELECT
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @StartDate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @EndDate)   = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                                AS [TotalWorkingDays]
```

**Result**

```
TotalWorkingDays
23
```

**Important Note**

> This method will only ignore Saturdays and Sundays, If you want to
>   exclude National Holidays and other seasonal Holidays you will need to
>   make use of a calender table as Zdravko Danev has already mentioned.

Comment: That is actually pretty cool way to do it. I would change the date names to numbers (since names could be different in different languages). to subtract holidays you can use a table.

Comment: @ZdravkoDanev well spotted I have updated it to use DATEPART instead of DATENAME

Comment: thank you @M.Ali, but what i'm looking for is a little bit different, I need to subtract a number of days from a date not 2 dates form each other, but that might give me an idea to start with.